# Can one keep shkiah of the Gra on one day and shkia of Rabenu taam the next day

Tags: halacha, tefilla, zemanim

I'm trying to understand zmanim.
When I go to work, I have to find a Mincha before I finish work at 5PM during the winter.
But according to the opinion of Rabeinu taam I can daven Mincha after work.
Can I keep Rabeinu taam during the week and Gra for Maariv on motzey shabbos as it's the only minyan available.
Or is this tartey disasrey.

Comment: What do you mean “can”? Both are opinions of Halacha, and theoretically you could change which you hold by due to change of opinion. But doing one at one time and another at another time seems like cognitive dissonance, no?

Comment: Tartei desasrei is a concept more relevant to where both psakim are accepted by the Gemara, not a dispute amongst Rishonim. That said, there are opinions that you can daven mincha post-sunset before nightfall even according to the Geonim/Gra (see Sha'ar Hatziyun in 233). For practical rulings consult a Rabbi

Comment: Reminds me of the discussion surrounding "early שבת" - with opponents of the summer-time practice similarly claiming that it often expresses a תרתי דסתרי (given that most are accustomed to strictly waiting until שקיעה for ערבית during the week).

Comment: @deutronomy This case is worse, as I pointed out above